# How to stop Visual Studio Query Builder from re-writing SQL (VS2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, query-builder, sqldatasource

I simply paste this SQL code that I've carefully crafted in SQL Server Management Studio and it works.

```
SELECT   v.StudentID, v.StudentName, s.StudentHomeEmailAddress, s.StudentStudyYear, s.StudentMobilePhone, t.TradeName, p.ProgramName, (CASE WHEN s.StudentHomeEmailAddress IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ord1
FROM     vwCurrentStudents AS v
         INNER JOIN tblStudents AS s ON s.StudentID = v.StudentID
         INNER JOIN tblStudentProgramReg AS r ON r.StudentID = s.StudentID AND r.StudProgEnrolStatusID IN (1, 3)
         INNER JOIN tblPrograms AS p ON r.ProgramID = p.ProgramID AND p.ProgramCatID IN (1, 3) AND p.ProgramID NOT IN (23, 112, 113)
         INNER JOIN tblTrades AS t ON t.TradeID = p.TradeID
WHERE    (@Who = 'Stu') 
  AND    (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) 
  AND    (
          (CASE WHEN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Programs, ',') AS mkTblP WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(p.ProgramName))))) = p.ProgramName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 OR dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Programs) = 1 OR @Programs = '%')
   AND    (CASE WHEN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Trades, ',') AS mkTblT WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(t.TradeName))))) = t.TradeName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 OR dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Trades) = 1 OR @Trades = '%')
         )
ORDER BY Ord1, v.StudentName
```

However, if I paste it into the Query Builder, where it attempts to generate table links etc... the query changes to this!

```
SELECT     v.StudentID, v.StudentName, s.StudentHomeEmailAddress, s.StudentStudyYear, s.StudentMobilePhone, t.TradeName, p.ProgramName, 
                      (CASE WHEN s.StudentHomeEmailAddress IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ord1
FROM         vwCurrentStudents AS v INNER JOIN
                      tblStudents AS s ON s.StudentID = v.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      tblStudentProgramReg AS r ON r.StudentID = s.StudentID AND r.StudProgEnrolStatusID IN (1, 3) INNER JOIN
                      tblPrograms AS p ON r.ProgramID = p.ProgramID AND p.ProgramCatID IN (1, 3) AND p.ProgramID NOT IN (23, 112, 113) INNER JOIN
                      tblTrades AS t ON t.TradeID = p.TradeID
WHERE     (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Programs, ',') AS mkTblP
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(p.ProgramName))))) = p.ProgramName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) AND 
                      (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Trades, ',') AS mkTblT
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(t .TradeName))))) = t .TradeName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Trades, ',') AS mkTblT
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(t .TradeName))))) = t .TradeName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) AND 
                      (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Programs) = 1) OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Trades, ',') AS mkTblT
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(t .TradeName))))) = t .TradeName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) AND 
                      (@Programs = '%') OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Programs, ',') AS mkTblP
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(p.ProgramName))))) = p.ProgramName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) AND 
                      (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Trades) = 1) OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Programs) = 1) AND (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Trades) = 1) OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (@Programs = '%') AND (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Trades) = 1) OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (CASE WHEN
                          (SELECT     Item
                            FROM          dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(@Programs, ',') AS mkTblP
                            WHERE      (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(Item))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(p.ProgramName))))) = p.ProgramName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) AND 
                      (@Trades = '%') OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (dbo.fnISEMPTY(@Programs) = 1) AND (@Trades = '%') OR
                      (@Who = 'Stu') AND (s.StudentStudyYear LIKE @StudyYear) AND (@Programs = '%') AND (@Trades = '%')
ORDER BY Ord1, v.StudentName
```

And it does not work. It's wrong. The placements of `ORs` and `ANDs` are wrong.

Is there an option or something I can do to stop this?

My only other option is to paste it into the ASP code view directly and carefully make sure it's SQL compliant as it does not like line breaks, ampersands, etc

Comment: Yes. Stop pasting it into Query Builder. If you don't want the SQL rewritten, don't use a feature of the IDE specifically designed to write the SQL for you. This is like the old joke: Patient: *Doctor, it hurts when I do this.* Doctor: *Then don't do that.* You're asking how to stop a tool designed from doing one thing from doing that one thing, and the answer is  to stop using that tool.

Comment: It's not that simple because sometimes pasting the SQL into the ASP code directly yields formatting errors due to spaces, tabs and pasting it into the sqldatasource SELECT sql window, puts a lot of UNICODE ascii characters in place of the <>, <=, >=, and other characters, making the SQL invalid when ported into other SQL engines. And besides I don't write the SQL in the builder. I use another program and copy/paste it into the builder just so it puts it the way I want into sqldatasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by turning off the display of the Query Builder's table layout. The code stays the way you pasted it. Thanks to @Ken for the tip, as sarcastic as it came about.